# macro succeeds when steps run separately, fails when run at once with 'error 424: object required'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with a macro that I'm writing to find blank cells in a column, cut and paste the rows to a new worksheet, and delete some columns.

Everything works when I run the steps in the macro separately. When I run them together in the same macro, it fails with "run time error 424 object required".

```
Sub Macro()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Columns("I").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft

Dim OldSheet As Worksheet

Set OldSheet = ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Sales - New Customers (Less Col").Range("1:2").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
'--> Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
OldSheet.Activate

Dim i As Long

    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 7) = "" Then
            Range("a" & i & ":I" & i).Copy Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Cells(i, 7).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

Range("G:G,H:H").Delete

End Sub
```

Running the macro steps separately succeeds.

I expect the macro to run once with no intervention and succeed.

Comment: Don‘t activate any sheet (only at the very end of your code, if you need another one on top). Use ws.Cells, ws.Rows, ws.Range etc. or Oldsheet.Cells, Oldsheet.Rows, Oldsheet.Range and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You defined "ws" and "Oldsheet" as worksheet - that is *good* practice - but you should use them consequently, as Excel otherwise has to guess every simple reference to a `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and will always use the Activesheet.

If you change the `Activesheet` by manual interaction, then you're lost.

**I suggest to use 3 characteristic references to worksheets, e. g. "OldSheet", "NewSheet" and "TemplateSheet", and to use them consequently.**

Please check first, if my usage of them is correct or if some of them have to be exchanged.

```
Option Explicit

Sub StructuredMacro()
    Dim OldSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TemplateSheet As Worksheet

    Set OldSheet = ActiveSheet
    OldSheet.Columns("I").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set NewSheet = ActiveSheet

    Set TemplateSheet = Sheets("Sales - New Customers (Less Col")
    TemplateSheet.Range("1:2").Copy
    NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    '--> NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths

    Dim i As Long
    For i = OldSheet.Cells(OldSheet.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If OldSheet.Cells(i, 7) = "" Then
            OldSheet.Range("a" & i & ":I" & i).Copy _
                NewSheet.Cells(NewSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            OldSheet.Cells(i, 7).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    OldSheet.Range("G:G,H:H").Delete

    ' activate a sheet only, when it should be seen on top afterwards
    NewSheet.Activate
End Sub
```